# Drupal 7, Fedora - dd() doesn't work for me over the web

Tags: permissions

I've designated the tmp directory to be `/tmp` (at the Drupal admin path `admin/config/media/file-system`).  This setting is confirmed by running `dpm(file_directory_temp());` from `devel/php`.

The permissions of `/tmp/drupal_debug.txt` (including SELinux settings, which I learned about [here](http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-drupal-7-on-fedora-linux)) are like so:

```
$ ls -ltZ /tmp/
-rwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 drupal_debug.txt
```

Further, if I run `dd("Foo")` from within the PHP CLI tool [`phpsh`](http://www.phpsh.org) using the [drush integration](https://drupal.org/project/phpsh) to get a bootstrapped Drupal environment, then I'm able to use `dd()`  to print to this file without issue.  Is there something additional I need to do to allow Apache to write to this file?

There are no errors in the Apache log, and notably, the issue persists even when I run `sudo setenforce 0`.

Another interesting point: the PHP test snippet from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752396/cant-write-to-tmp-with-php-despite-777-permissions-and-no-open-basedir-value) returns "Success" when I run it from `devel/php`, in other words Drupal does feel it can write to an arbitrary file in `/tmp`.  However, if I modify the code to the following form:

```
 $handle = fopen("/tmp/drupal_debug.txt", "x");
 if ($handle) echo "Success!";
 else print_r(error_get_last());
```

**then** I get this warning, and no success message:

> Warning: fopen(/tmp/drupal_debug.txt): failed to open stream: File exists in eval() (line 1 of /srv/www/decipher-storyscope/public_html/decipher/7f/profiles/storyscope/modules/contrib/devel/devel.module(1285) : eval()'d code).

This is true even if I *delete* the `/tmp/drupal_debug.txt` file.

However, as discussed in the comments, no file is created when running this snippet over the web, whereas, an empty file *is* created if I run the same snippet from the PHP command line.

*NB.* The function works fine when the code is installed and `dd()` called on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got advice from my sysadmin: put the `tmp` directory in `/srv/www`.

```
shell> sudo mkdir /srv/www/my-project/tmp
shell> sudo chmod a+w /srv/www/my-project/tmp
```

and in Drupal's `settings.php`:

```
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = '/srv/www/my-project/tmp';
```

Then: `tail -f /srv/www/my-project/tmp/drupal_debug.txt` works.